# Changing style of overlay container

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I use a git project for a virtual keyboard (https://ngx-material-keyboard.github.io/demo/). And I have some issues to get it running on a small device with 450*250 pixel.

At the end I found the necessary changes in the css if I modify it directly at the web browser with dev tools.

Now I have to find the right position to change the sources.

There will be used the overlay component from angular2-material to visualize the keyboard.

If I comment out the position in the cdk-overlay-container, it works:

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
/* position: fixed; */
z-index: 1000;
```

}

But I cant overwrite these from my angular application.
Any suggestions?

[Screenshot of changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0IUS.png)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> **UPDATED ANSWER**

From the official documentation:

> **Styling overlay components**
>
> Overlay-based components have a panelClass
> property (or similar) that can be used to target the overlay pane.

You can override the default dialog container styles by adding a css class in your global **`styles.css`**. For example:

```
.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
    /* add your styles */
}
```

After that, you'll need to providies you css class as a **`panelClass`** parameter to your dialog:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container' })
```

Read this [**official documentation**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md) for more information.

---

> **ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Use `::ng-deep` in your component.css to override the default styles.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    /* Do you changes here */
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that ::ng-deep is deprecated - but I can't find clarification on timeframes or alternatives

Comment: ::ng-deep doesn't stay in isolated scope, it will effect other views too

Comment: What if i need to set z-index of .cdk-overlay-container for mat-menu and mat-dialog separately. as i have fixed header on my site

Comment: For this case `::ng-deep` effectively does the same as to put the css code in the global styles. You're better off putting it in global styles - because it isn't scoped to your component. In fact it's worse than that - lets say you put background: blue - and opened a dialog from another component. It wouldn't be blue right. But then you open this component and it's blue - great! Then go back and open the first one again and it will still be blue. This belongs in global styles.css or scss.

Comment: Also, isn't `::ng-deep` deprecated now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep

Answer (score 4):

To be able to override the Material CSS classes from your component styles, you will need to set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'], //or .css, depending what you use
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the styling of mat-dialogue-container adding a panel class and giving style is enough, but in case if you want to change the styling of cdk-overlay-container then adding a backdropClass will help

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
  backdropClass: 'popupBackdropClass',
  panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container',
  data: { data: data }
});
```

in css add

```
.popupBackdropClass {
   background-color:yellow
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding cdk-overlay-containeris not good since it is gonna affect all other components. You can create custom `OverlayContainer`. See [example](https://www.bbogdanov.dev/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container).

Answer (score 0):

I found that by using the main/default "Styles.css". Styling changes for the CDK (as well as Material and Animations) are picked-up properly. (caveat) I am using Angular 4 .

Answer (score 0):

I sort it out myself by using two stylessheet one `Global` and other `component's` stylesheet, In global i set `z-index` to to lower value(`1000`) so that it goes behind the `header` and in `popup` component styles sheet i set that to high value(`2000`) with `!important` so that header goes behind my overlay.

That's how i manage to solve it.

Thank me later

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, because the css classes inside the component's css file, will influence the whole app.
The best way is the one suggested by @Faisal

Answer (score 0):

I thought up a better(mmm.. more interesting maybe) way to do this by using the `:has()` css selector. Even though you can't set the class of the `.cdk-overlay-container` you can set the `panelClass` of the `cdk-overlay-pane`. If you set the panelClass in your dialog config you can then add a **::ng-deep** statement in the component scss file that uses that panelClass to target the cdk-overlay-container element that contains an element with that matching panelClass.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    panelClass: 'my-dialog-panel',
    hasBackdrop: false
});
```

then in the scss file add a:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container:has(.my-dialog-panel) {
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

you could also avoid the ng-deep and just add it to the global styles too and the class would still be reasonably isolated compared to the alternatives.