# angular material datepicker doesn't open in modal dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material2

I have an angular material 2 date-picker implemented in a bootstrap modal form:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> 
        <div class="timeline-cal">
            <input class="date-field" [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
            <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
            <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn grey-btn pull-right"     (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, upon clicking the button, the datepicker wouldn't open in the modal dialog itself but opens in the background. I tried this but didn't help:

```
.mat-datepicker-content{    z-index: 1200}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: @kenfire Not yet!

Comment: Can you add some example code in a jsfiddle? Don't forget to select the same framework you are using so we can replicate the issue.

Comment: @yurzui nope, same behaviour

Comment: @qwertoyo Can you provide plunker?

Comment: @yurzui: I have found the issue. It was me not knowing the correct way to style angular >=2 material components :)

reference: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

and if you're using webpack, you'll need to-string-loader

Comment: modal in modal - that is an akward user experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing style of overlay container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610137/changing-style-of-overlay-container)

Answer (score 4):

try,

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}
```

Or this

```
/deep/ .cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```css
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 100000 !important; /* set value you need */
}
```

You have to specify certain position for z-index.

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).
>   [CSS z-index @ W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the component html file :

```
<style>
  ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
    z-index: 2000;
</style>
```

Hope fully this will resolve the issue !!!