# Jquery UI datepicker in an Angular Material table

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, angular-material2

I am trying to use a jquery UI datepicker in an angular material table cell:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="dt">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Date </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" contenteditable='false' > 
          <div class="timeline-cal">
            <md-form-field class="input-full-width">
              <input mdInput class="date-field cursor-pointer" type="text" readonly>
            </md-form-field>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
          </div>
     </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In `ts` file:

```
ngOnInit() 
{
/*-----------------JQuery UI Calender control settings---------------------------*/

    console.log('jquery::::::', $);
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
        $('.date-field').datepicker();
    }, 200);
}
```

The issue is that the datepicker won't open. However when I include the datepicker outside the table, it opens perfectly fine.

[I suspect the main problem is that the jquery popup won't open inside an angular material component. I had faced the same issue while trying to open angular material datepicker inside a bootstrap modal form: [angular material datepicker doesn't open in modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094320/angular-material-datepicker-doesnt-open-in-modal-dialog) ]