# Override Angular Material 2 MdDatepicker's top or left offset from trigger

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2, offset

I am using the **Angular Material 2** `MdDatepicker` in a side navigation. On mobile the view port is not wide enough to not obfuscate the date-picker when open. I have included an image here to show you what it looks like open.

[image]

Currently the left offset for this date-picker is 197.5px from the left. This style is inline and not easily overridden. I would like to find a way to either override this with CSS (I can not figure that out) or import he `MdDatepicker` in my `component.ts` file and override it's behavior or anything else you can think of. I need that number to be `44px`, not `197.5px`.

Below is the inline code I pulled out of the developer tools. The date-picker open up inside of a cdk-overlay and is offset within that div.

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-1" class="cdk-overlay-pane" 
dir="ltr" style="pointer-events: auto; top: 416px; left: 197.5px;">
```

I am new to material and I'm hoping that even without support from Angular Material to do this, we can find a hack to do it. I would need to apply this offset only to certain date-pickers, not all of them. However, I would mark this answer accepted with a simple solution to adjust and customize that offset left or offset top position. I figure if I can do one I can do the other just as easily, I have looked into the `MdDateicker` code in the node_module and it is not apparent to me how to override this component.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a mat-datepicker that also has the cdk-overlay-pane, I found the solution for editing the styles in another post.
[Changing style of overlay container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610137/changing-style-of-overlay-container)

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container {
  top: 416px;
  left: 197.5px;
}
```

Comment: In my case I also have a popup mat-menu that doesn't work with this change, but using the mat-datepicker you can set the styles like this: ::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-popup