# Using Material Autocomplete for inline editing with ag-grid

Tags: angular-material2, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I am facing issues while trying to use [angular-material](/questions/tagged/angular-material) `Autocomplete` for doing inline edit.

Created plunk for the same: [Material Autocomplete for Inline Edit - ag-grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFZsMmb6l1eMczBd0Vkf?p=preview)

1. Autocomplete options are not coming at the expected position. I have to scroll down below the bottom of the grid to see the options.
2. Once I select any option, I am not able to see the updated value in the row - I just see blank value instead.

Tried providing various values for `isPopup?(): boolean { return false; }` for #1 and `getValue() { return this.selectedValue; }` for #2, but not getting any clue what's the actual issue is.

What I want is,

1. The options to get displayed at proper position - like what we see while using normal material autocomplete
2. The options to get displayed as soon as I open the cell for editing - as of now, I have to click inside the editing cell.
3. Once I am done with selecting appropriate value, it should also be updated in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first case could be solved via overriding `.cdk-overlay-pane`, just add `styles` block to your `AutocompleteEditor` component

```
styles: [`
    ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
        /* Do you changes here */
        position: fixed; // <- only this one is crucial
        z-index: 1000;
        background:white
    }
`],
```

Partially got answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617481/4483102)

> The second, you have to take care of `focus` by your self, so the easiest way to create another `ViewChild` reference and add it to material input as example `#cInput`

```
@ViewChild('cInput') public cInput;
afterGuiAttached?(): void {
    this.cInput.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

> The third case, use option instead of `value` inside `_autoCompleteChanged` function

```
_autoCompleteChanged(option) {
  this.selectedValue = option; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I (facepalm)ed for silly mistake in  `_autoCompleteChanged`.

Comment: The selection does not happen when grid is having `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` set to `true`.